# Why can't I track progress towards a [mass-effect] tag badge?

Tags: support, badges

For some reason, [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect) does not show up in the "Track your next tag badge" widget:

[image: Screenshot of the tag selector when searching for "mass-effect". It's empty.]

I have a lot more progress towards [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect) than towards any of these tags:

[image: Screenshot of the tag selector with a bunch of random tags, for which I have very little progress.]

So what gives? Why can't I track the badge that I actually have a chance of getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the main Meta post on tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/398063):

> ### What tags are eligible for badges?
>
> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be eligible for tag badges.

We currently have 68 [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect) questions, so I'm guessing the system doesn't track an ineligible badge.

All the other tags in your screenshot have more than 100 questions (so are eligible).

Comment: Ah, so I don't have a chance of getting it any time soon. Well, that's a bit demoralizing. Oh well.

Comment: @Kevin 32 questions doesn't seem that much to go on, though I guess that depends on how you define "soon". Hook some friends into it and point them to SFF afterwards ;P (or, don't forget that you can come up with questions and self-answers of your own, that's encouraged by SE - provided they're of quality, of course)